# UnrecognizedClientException while testing API Gateway with integration type Kinesis

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis

I have created an API using API gateway with integration type 'Kinesis'. I am trying to access ListStreams method. I have created a role with AmazonKinesisFullAccess policy and trusted identity is set to apigateway.amazonaws.com. I have provided arn to the execution role field but while testing this API using console, getting following error:

```
<UnrecognizedClientException>
  <Message>The security token included in the request is invalid</Message>
</UnrecognizedClientException>
```

Thanks

Comment: My bad, I had entered the wrong region. But aws should have thrown a meaningful error that could guide me to the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This was a classic example of wrong/incomplete exception detail.

My fault was that I was looking for kinesis in a wrong region. But rather than returning some error like "Resource not found", api gateway returned "Invalid security token".